# How can i parse html string

Tags: c#, asp.net, html

I have a html string and i want to parse this;

```html
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head id="Head1" runat="server">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table>
            <tr class="MyColumn">
                <td colspan="2">
                    &nbsp;&nbsp;<b>Team List</b>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr valign="top">
                <td width="313">
                    &nbsp;<img src="weight.gif" width="11" height="10" alt="Encumbrance: 0" title="Encumbrance: 0">&nbsp;
                    <a href="Test.asp?action=ViewItemDetails&ItemTypeiD=1">Real Madrid</a>
                </td>
                <td align="right" width="140">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr valign="top">
                <td width="313">
                    &nbsp;<img src="weight.gif" width="11" height="10" alt="Encumbrance: 1" title="Encumbrance: 1">&nbsp;
                    <a href="Test.asp?action=ViewItemDetails&ItemTypeID=2">Barcelona</a>
                </td>
                <td align="right" width="140">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="MyColumn">
                <td colspan="2">
                    &nbsp;&nbsp;<b>Money List</b>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr valign="top">
                <td width="313">
                    &nbsp;<img src="weight.gif" width="11" height="10" alt="Encumbrance: 0" title="Encumbrance: 0">&nbsp;
                    <a href="Test.asp?action=ViewItemDetails&ItemTypeiD=1">$</a>
                </td>
                <td align="right" width="140">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr valign="top">
                <td width="313">
                    &nbsp;<img src="weight.gif" width="11" height="10" alt="Encumbrance: 1" title="Encumbrance: 1">&nbsp;
                    <a href="Test.asp?action=ViewItemDetails&ItemTypeID=2">€</a>
                </td>
                <td align="right" width="140">
                </td>
            </tr>            
        </table>
    </body>
    </html>
```

how can I do this;

Best Regards

Comment: sorry not clear what you mean - do you mean you want to load the html, turn it into data, and then be able to alter it (potentially pushing it back to html?) or do you just want to ***read*** it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(html);

var teams = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//td[@width='313']")
                .Select(td => new TeamClass
                {
                    TeamName = td.Element("a").InnerText,
                    TeamId = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(td.Element("a").Attributes["href"].Value)["ItemTypeID"]
                })
                .ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It is working fine. But can i want to something about that. this html iside Team List, Money List, Song List etc. You can see in my html;
<td colspan="2">
            &nbsp;&nbsp;<b>Team List</b>
        </td>

I want to only take <b>Team List<b>

how can I do that ?

Comment: @emozguner Can not answer without knowing full html.

Comment: full html is my first post. always repeat
<tr class="MyColumn">
        <td colspan="2">
            &nbsp;&nbsp;<b>Team List</b>
        </td>
    </tr>
<tr class="MyColumn">
        <td colspan="2">
            &nbsp;&nbsp;<b>Money List</b>
        </td>
    </tr>

firstly I want to take if html ==
<td colspan="2">
            &nbsp;&nbsp;<b>Team List</b>
        </td>
After run yours code. First level is if this html == Team List. Can u help me ?

Comment: @emozguner I am not sure I can understand your question, but, if what  you want is the title of a table then you can try `var title = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//tr[@class='MyColumn']/td/b").InnerText`

Comment: I want to this but my code give error. maybe you can help;Firstly I want to parse Team List after I want to team so. I must take Node hasgot Team List afterthat i must run your code i send code like this;

Comment: var parsedValues =
                doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("b/'Team List'").SelectMany(
                    info => info.SelectNodes("//td[@width='313']"), (info, dtElement) => new { info, dtElement }).Select(
                        td => new Items
                            {
                                ItemName = td.dtElement.Element("a").InnerText,
                                ItemTypeID =
                                    HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(td.dtElement.Element("a").Attributes["href"].Value)["ItemTypeID"],

                            }).ToList();

Comment: But I want to replace SelectNodes("b/'Team List'") to <td colspan="2">
            &nbsp;&nbsp;<b>Team List</b>
        </td> how can I do this?
Best Regards for your answer and interest

Comment: Select `"//tr[@class='MyColumn']/td/b"` and see if its inner text is `Team List` or not.

Comment: how can I put this to your code can u update your answer like this?
Thanks for your answer
Best Regards

Comment: @emozguner it is in one of my previous comments.

Comment: i cant understand. because when i write this it's take only one title. can u write full code again for answer this question? 
Regards

Comment: List<Items> teams;
            teams = new List<Items>();
            foreach (HtmlNode td in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//td[@width='313']"))
            {
                var title = td.SelectSingleNode("//tr[@class='MyColumn']/td/b").InnerText;
                if (title=="Team List")
                {
                    teams.Add(new Items
                    {
                        ItemName = td.Element("a").InnerText,
                        ItemTypeID = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(td.Element("a").Attributes["href"].Value)["ItemTypeID"],
            }

Comment: I get all Team List, Money List again. But I want to only Team List and their childs?

Comment: Sorry @emozguner I just try to help here blindly and this is all I can do with the limited html you posted. No `body`, no `table` etc. Maybe there are other criteria to locate the correct table/rows easily.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this lib http:[HTML Agility Pack](http://html-agility-pack.net).
It helps you with HTML parsing.

Comment: i think it is like using a sledge-hammer to crack a nut.

Comment: @DmitryDovgopoly - Except the correct tool in question actually is the `HTML Agility Pack` regular expression would be difficult for the author since they likely are a novice at programming.  Honestly using a regular expression seems like the sledge-hammer, a very heavy one, because of the overhead.

Comment: Ok, but for me it seems that extrnal library plus link queries are harder, than regex

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Regular expression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression)

```
String html; //your html string
String pattern = @"action=ViewItemDetails&ItemType[I|i]D=(\d*)"">(.*)</a>";
MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(html, pattern);
var list = new List<TeamClass>();
foreach (Match match in matches)
{
    TeamClass team = new TeamClass();
    team.TeamName = match.Groups[2].Value;
    team.TeamId = Int32.Parse(match.Groups[1].Value);
    list.Add(team);
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. but matches count ==0 it doesnt find.

Comment: fixed. In your text example you have different ItemTypeID spelling(ID and iD)

Answer (score 0):

Try [Html Agility](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Examples):

try something like (Untested Code):

```
var TeamList = from lnks in document.DocumentNode.Descendants()
               where lnks.Name == "a" && 
                    lnks.Attributes["href"] != null && 
                    lnks.InnerText.Trim().Length > 0
               select new
               {

                  TeamId= (lnks.Attributes["href"].Value).
                          Substring((lnks.Attributes["href"].Value).Length-1, 1),
                  TeamName= lnks.InnerText
               };
```

Comment: where is temp variable ? cannot resolve this?

Comment: var document = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
            document.Load(result);
            var TeamList = from lnks in document.DocumentNode.Descendants()
                           where lnks.Name == "a" &&
                                 lnks.Attributes["href"] != null &&
                                 lnks.InnerText.Trim().Length > 0
                           select new
                               {
                                   TeamId = (lnks.Attributes["href"].Value),
                                   TeamName = lnks.InnerText
                               };

Comment: This get all link in this page. I want to only TeamId and TeamName under the Team List How Can I do this in your code?

Regards

Comment: Then you have to show all html ! the answer refers to the posted code.

Comment: I cant edit my code full code 
http://www.2shared.com/document/9nU8caja/New_Text_Document__4_.html

regards